# Money management: limit the asset quantity displayed to the value of my portfolio

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I use a money management indicator.

When I move the stoploss closer to my buy price then my position size also increases which makes sense, and I didn't want the position size to be bigger than my Balance so I did this:

```
NewBalance = PositionSize > Balance ? Balance : PositionSize
```

But here's my problem:

When I bring the stoploss closer to my buy price then the asset quantity also increases which makes sense but how do I make that the asset quantity displayed doesn't exceed the value of my Balance?

Do you have an idea?

Comment: Did you try?
`NewAssetQuantity = AssetQuantity > Balance ? Balance : AssetQuantity`

This will set `NewAssetQuantity` to be the minimum of either your calculated `AssetQuantity` or your Balance. This way, your asset quantity won't exceed your available balance.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I don't think it's right because when AssetQuantity (example 1.6 BTC) won't be bigger than my portfolio